# Powers of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, real-numbers, symmetric-matrices

Let $\sigma_i$ be a $n$-dimensional vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. And $S$ a matrix where each row is the $i$-th $\sigma$ vector

\begin{equation}
S = \begin{pmatrix}  
        \sigma_1 \\
        \sigma_2 \\
        \vdots \\
        \sigma_P
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Therefore I can write $R = S \times S^T$ as
\begin{equation}
R = S \times S^T = \begin{pmatrix}  
        \langle \sigma_1 , \sigma_1 \rangle & %
        \langle \sigma_1 , \sigma_2 \rangle & %
        \cdots &
        \langle \sigma_1 , \sigma_P \rangle \\
        \langle \sigma_2 , \sigma_1 \rangle &
        \langle \sigma_2 , \sigma_2 \rangle &
        \cdots &
        \langle \sigma_2 , \sigma_P \rangle \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        \langle \sigma_P , \sigma_1 \rangle &
        \langle \sigma_P , \sigma_2 \rangle &
        \cdots &
        \langle \sigma_P , \sigma_P \rangle 
        \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

To make things more visible, by dot product commutativity I can rewrite R as

\begin{equation}
R = S \times S^T = \begin{pmatrix}  
        \langle \sigma_1 , \sigma_1 \rangle & %
        \langle \sigma_1 , \sigma_2 \rangle & %
        \cdots &
        \langle \sigma_1 , \sigma_P \rangle \\
        \langle \sigma_1 , \sigma_2 \rangle &
        \langle \sigma_2 , \sigma_2 \rangle &
        \cdots &
        \langle \sigma_2 , \sigma_P \rangle \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        \langle \sigma_1 , \sigma_P \rangle &
        \langle \sigma_2 , \sigma_P \rangle &
        \cdots &
        \langle \sigma_P , \sigma_P \rangle 
        \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

How can I describe $R^2$ without perform all calculations? Is there any way to generalize a rule to describe the $n$-th power of $R$?

By describe, I mean, write it down in matrix form without perform all calculations. Also If there is any properties that emerge that help to know the form and its elements.

For example, I know that a product of symmetric matrices are also symmetric, therefore I just need to calculate the upper triangular (or lower if I feel down). Any other "caveats"?

Comment: Define *describe*.